# Finding a certain function with some requirements

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I want to solve the following problem:

Let $C,E\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $C$ is compact,$E$ is closed and $ C\cap E = \emptyset$. Show that there exist a function $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R^n})$ such that $f = 1$ in $C$ and $f = 0$ in $E$.

My attempt:

I want to invoke the following lemma:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be open and $C \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ compact such that $C \subset U$. Then there exist $\phi \in C^\infty$ such that $\phi=1$ in $C$ and supp$\phi \subset U$

Then we take $U=E^{c}$ and we are done, because this means that $f=1$ in $C$ and supp$f \subset U$ and this implies that $f = 0$ in $E$.

Am I right? thanks in advance :).

Comment: I think you want to *invoke* that lemma, but otherwise this looks good.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) and yes, invoke, but then everything find and righ :), correct?

Comment: Yes, as I said, everything else looks good. Nice work.

Comment: Given that the lemma pretty much trivialises the problem, maybe you need to prove the lemma too?

Comment: We have already prove that in class :) and well yes is a lot of work